# Heroku deployment not working with postgresql api

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, heroku, heroku-addon

I am working on a nodejs api found on https://www.taniarascia.com/node-express-postgresql-heroku/
it uses postgresql so it requires you to download the postgresql add-on to your app on heroku witch I did, but when I open the app it says cannot get / like expected but I go to the /books and it gives me the heroku error. When I do:

```sh
heroku logs -t -a node-api-with-books
```

it gives me this error:

```
2021-03-03T03:25:31.515099+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2021-03-03T03:25:31.515099+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2021-03-03T03:25:31.515099+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2021-03-03T03:25:31.515100+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
2021-03-03T03:25:31.515100+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-03-03T03:25:31.542497+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/books" host=node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com request_id=83db8d38-c206-484a-8bca-a273ed8be8bd fwd="66.7.125.54" dyno=web.1 connect=5002ms service=95ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-03T03:25:31.578446+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-03T03:25:31.579040+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-03-03T03:25:31.653173+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! working-rest-api@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2021-03-03T03:25:31.653743+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-03-03T03:25:31.656417+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-03T03:25:31.656729+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the working-rest-api@1.0.0 start script.
2021-03-03T03:25:31.657018+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-03T03:25:31.693198+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-03T03:25:31.700905+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-03T03:25:31.701084+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-03T03_25_31_668Z-debug.log
2021-03-03T03:25:31.868076+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-03T03:25:32.005535+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-03-03T03:25:32.847159+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com request_id=d669a8bb-5c76-4007-8e20-2323df702196 fwd="66.7.125.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2021-03-03T03:57:13.968272+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-03T03:57:19.191432+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-03T03:57:23.003539+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-03T03:57:23.003564+00:00 app[web.1]: > working-rest-api@1.0.0 start /app
2021-03-03T03:57:23.003565+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2021-03-03T03:57:23.003565+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-03T03:57:23.514091+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening
2021-03-03T03:57:23.596725+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-03T04:31:59.242314+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2021-03-03T04:31:59.270196+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2021-03-03T04:32:00.860211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2021-03-03T04:32:01.033002+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2021-03-04T23:41:06.257484+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2021-03-04T23:41:06.279151+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2021-03-04T23:41:09.533736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-04T23:41:13.424801+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-04T23:41:13.424844+00:00 app[web.1]: > working-rest-api@1.0.0 start /app
2021-03-04T23:41:13.424844+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2021-03-04T23:41:13.424844+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-04T23:41:13.856750+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening
2021-03-04T23:41:14.426074+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-04T23:41:15.345417+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com request_id=1fafdcec-9742-41d6-a530-a15755f7f0cc fwd="66.7.125.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=11ms status=404 bytes=415 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464200+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/index.js:12
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464217+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464218+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464218+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464219+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464222+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464223+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464223+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464223+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464224+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464224+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
2021-03-04T23:41:20.464225+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-03-04T23:41:20.477571+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/books" host=node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com request_id=24e2da67-be91-4e17-89b3-debef869bba4 fwd="66.7.125.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=49ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:41:20.484562+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-04T23:41:20.485036+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-03-04T23:41:20.493801+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! working-rest-api@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2021-03-04T23:41:20.494105+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-03-04T23:41:20.494432+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-04T23:41:20.494669+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the working-rest-api@1.0.0 start script.
2021-03-04T23:41:20.494947+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-04T23:41:20.511921+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-04T23:41:20.512219+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-04T23:41:20.512381+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-04T23_41_20_495Z-debug.log
2021-03-04T23:41:20.920060+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-04T23:41:20.981301+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-03-04T23:41:21.001047+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2021-03-04T23:41:24.349422+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2021-03-04T23:41:28.760560+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-04T23:41:28.760604+00:00 app[web.1]: > working-rest-api@1.0.0 start /app
2021-03-04T23:41:28.760605+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2021-03-04T23:41:28.760605+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-04T23:41:29.460226+00:00 app[web.1]: Server listening
2021-03-04T23:41:29.767594+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782783+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/index.js:12
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782799+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782800+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782800+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782801+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782802+00:00 app[web.1]: at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1146:16) {
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782802+00:00 app[web.1]: errno: -111,
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782803+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782803+00:00 app[web.1]: syscall: 'connect',
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782803+00:00 app[web.1]: address: '127.0.0.1',
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782804+00:00 app[web.1]: port: 5432
2021-03-04T23:41:30.782804+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-03-04T23:41:30.806119+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/books" host=node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com request_id=0476a454-a185-465c-9df3-f5e0adf6ec8f fwd="66.7.125.54" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=143ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2021-03-04T23:41:30.897859+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2021-03-04T23:41:30.901791+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2021-03-04T23:41:30.940174+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! working-rest-api@1.0.0 start: `node index.js`
2021-03-04T23:41:30.941393+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2021-03-04T23:41:30.942380+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2021-03-04T23:41:30.942813+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the working-rest-api@1.0.0 start script.
2021-03-04T23:41:30.943425+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-03-04T23:41:31.316808+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-03-04T23:41:31.316994+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2021-03-04T23:41:31.317190+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2021-03-04T23_41_30_947Z-debug.log
2021-03-04T23:41:31.419624+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-03-04T23:41:31.527952+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2021-03-04T23:41:32.128408+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com request_id=7909f853-52aa-43dc-a228-3190e28b31b9 fwd="66.7.125.54" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Is there any part of this that I should focus on and how do I make it work?

You might need to look at this to understand better https://www.taniarascia.com/node-express-postgresql-heroku/

Answer (score 2):

Your are trying to connect to local postgreSQL database from heroku, try to set  a new environment variable in heroku dashboard like this :

`NODE_ENV=production`

### or

You need to set up all your env. var with add-ons value like this :

```
DB_USER=[your-add-on-user]
DB_PASSWORD=[your-add-on-pass]
DB_HOST=[your-add-on-host]
DB_PORT=5432
DB_DATABASE=[your-add-on-database]
```

source : https://www.taniarascia.com/node-express-postgresql-heroku/#environment-variables

Comment: So where would I put that on heroku?

Comment: here -> https://dashboard.heroku.com/apps > click on your app > go to settings tab > click on `Reveal Config var` > enter the new var

Comment: It is still saying "application error" and I put NODE_ENV as the var and production as the value

Comment: Are the log different ? or is't still `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432`?

Comment: No it still says ```Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:5432```

Comment: did you follow those instructions here > https://www.taniarascia.com/node-express-postgresql-heroku/#set-up-postgresql-connection ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229540/discussion-between-victor-bls-and-gticlicker).

Comment: This worked at first but now it is not working again I also created another api and it doesn't work either do you think you could help me?

Comment: Can you post another question ? If it's the same error could you please add me as a collaborator ?

Comment: Yes I'll add you as a collaborator on both projects

Comment: There you are added. Did you find anything useful?

Comment: I need access to the code as the errors aren't specific

Comment: I've added you on GitHub were I put the code

Comment: Have you found anything?

Comment: Have you found a way to fix it?

Comment: Try to debug it with my answer or, if it's new error (other than `ECONNREFUSED`), you can create a new question.

Comment: Ok thanks. I posted a new question because it no longer says ```ECONNREFUSED```